# Is it possible to design a Quantum Computing Advantage to deploy an application on the web?

Tags: experimental-realization, quantum-advantage, applications

I need to understand the frontier and practical applications of quantum computing.
Is it possible to design a Quantum Computing Advantage to deploy an application on the web, such as a browser, modeling molecules, bot writing code, and other very specific applications?
can a quantum computer work with the internet/web of today ?

Answer (score 2):

Quantum computing is not a tool to be used for general purpose computing. In general for most common computer programs quantum computing, even on a perfect machine, would provide little advantage over a CPU. In these programs there is no need to use quantum features such as entanglement. May be you could run programs more efficiently, but then it makes more sense to then just build custom circuits using an FPGA as an accelerator.

The main advantages currently are in scientific modelling, more specifically for combinatorial optimisations, and simulations. This is because we can take advantage of quantum mechanical effects to help evaluate possibilities more efficiently than sampling on a CPU. However, as of today implementations are limited to noisy hardware, and the most reliable algorithms are usually hybrids, such as variational algorithms, where we use the QPU to encode the problem, whilst we still rely upon classical subroutines.

So algorithms such as factoring or HHL, are still considering slightly out of reach of todays QPU, due to the current level of noise and limited qubits that makes it hard to produce reliable results for a purely quantum program.